# C++ How to pass a variable char array from one function to another

Tags: c++, variables, arrays

I have a question regarding passing a variable that is a char array from one function into the next.

Here are the samples of code involved:

```
int main( int argc, char** argv )
{

int value = 0;

int nCounter = 0;
FILE* fIn = NULL;
char * sLine = new char[MAX_FILENAME_SIZE];
char * sFileName = new char [MAX_FILENAME_SIZE];
char * s = new char [MAX_FILENAME_SIZE];



if ((fIn = fopen(ImgListFileName,"rt"))==NULL)

{
    printf("Failed to open file: %s\n",ImgListFileName);
    return nCounter;
}



while(!feof(fIn)){

//set the variables to 0
memset(sLine,0,MAX_FILENAME_SIZE*sizeof(char));
memset(sFileName,0,MAX_FILENAME_SIZE*sizeof(char));
memset(s,0,MAX_FILENAME_SIZE*sizeof(char));
//read one line (one image filename)
//sLine will contain one line from the text file
fgets(sLine,MAX_FILENAME_SIZE,fIn);
//copy the filename into variable s
strncpy(s, sLine, strlen(sLine)-1);
//put a \0 character at the end of the filename
strcat(sLine,"\0");
//create the filename
strcat(sFileName,s);

nCounter++;


fclose(fIn);
delete sLine;
delete sFileName;
delete s;
    const int size = 60;
    char path[size] = "path";
    strcat(path,sFileName);

    printf (path);
IplImage *img = cvLoadImage(path);
detect_and_draw(img);
cvWaitKey();
cvReleaseImage(&img);
cvDestroyWindow("result");

void detect_and_draw( IplImage* img )
{


More code that isn't involved....


cvSaveImage(sFileName, img);
```

Now, I have tried the following:

```
void getFilename(char * sFileName)
{
    printf("The filename is %s\n", sFileName);
    return;
}
```

And then call with

```
char * S ="string"
getFilename(S);
cvSaveImage(S,img);
```

But "string" is placed into "The filename is: string".

What can I do so that I can use sFileName, the char array, in cvSaveImage(sFileName, img)?

Thanks in advance, and if you need any further clarifications, please ask!

Comment: `char * S ="string"` should be `const char *S...`. String literals are read-only memory. Even better, `std::string`.

Comment: You should use `delete[]` to deallocate arrays (`sLine`, `sFileName`, `s`).

Comment: When doing that, I end up getting 'getFilename' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const char *' to 'char *' Same with std::string.

Comment: @Michael, Then change `getFilename`. If you can't do that and you're sure it doesn't change anything, `const_cast`. Otherwise, copy it into a new array.

Comment: What have you tried, and how is it (not) working? Your intended use of `cvSaveImage(sFileName, img)` should be fine, as long as `sFileName` is NUL-terminated, which it appears it should be (and of course, assuming there aren't problems with `img`, as well).

Comment: @twalberg, The issue is that sFileName is defined in an earlier function, and I need to pass it and its value over to the void function. Img also does not have any issues.

Comment: @chris, Change getFilename to const char * sFileName?

Comment: @Michael Yes, then it can take const data. Const-correctness is always a good thing to have.

Comment: @chris, It still spits out "The filename is: string"

Comment: @AlanStokes, I'd love to use it, but it appears as though cvSaveImage wants const char *

Comment: @Michael, It wasn't meant to fix this immediate problem, but if you continue casting literals to non-const pointers, you'll end up with a weird problem you don't know how to fix someday.

Comment: @Michael: Use `std::string`, and when `cvSaveImage` requires a `char const *`, use the string's `.c_str()` member function to get it.

Comment: Pretty fair to guess that `delete sFileName; [...] strcat(path, sFileName);` may be causing part of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, what you have is a scoping problem. You essentially have:

```
int main(/* */)
{ char sFileName[MAX_FILENAME_SIZE];

  /* code to initialize sFileName to contain a value */

  detect_and_draw(img);
}

void detect_and_draw(IplImage *img)
{ cvSaveImage(sFileName, img);
}
```

The problem is that `sFileName` is local to `main()` and not accessible in `detect_and_draw()`. You can either modify `detect_and_draw()` to take a second argument:

```
int main()
{ /* stuff */
  detect_and_draw(img, sFileName);
}
void detect_and_draw(IplImage *img, const char* fn)
{ cvSaveImage(fn, img);
}
```

Or make sFileName a global variable declared/defined outside the scope of `main()` - although that's quite often considered to be an inferior solution.

Comment: It doesn't seem to allow me to give detect_and_draw 2 arguments.

Comment: How so? What error do you get? Off the top of my head, there may be a header file that also contains a declaration for `detect_and_draw()`, which you would also need to modify to specify the additional argument.

Comment: Actually, it does allow it. I didn't realize it, but I had a bit of old code left over that I didn't even notice that limited the arguments to only 1. Otherwise, your solution works perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Ignoring the undefined behavior, unnecessary dynamic allocation, etc., what you seem to be trying to accomplish boils down to something on this general order:

```
std::string path;

while (std::getline(fIn, path)) {
    std::cout << "path: " << path;

    IplImage *img = cvLoadImage(path.c_str());

    detect_and_draw(img, path);
    cvWaitKey();
    cvReleaseImage(&img);

    cvDestroyWindow("result");    
}

void detect_and_draw(IpImage *img, std::string const &path) { 
// ...
    cvSaveImage(path.c_str(), img);
}
```

I think I'd do things a bit differently from that though -- probably starting with an `Image` class, something like:

```
class Image { 
    IpImage *img;
    std::string path;

public:
    Image(std::string const &name) : 
        img(cvLoadImage(name.c_str()), path(name) 
    { }

    ~Image() { cvReleaseImage(&img); }

    void detect_and_draw() { 
         // ...
         cvSaveImage(path);
    }
};
```

Using that, your code would look more like this:

```
while (std::getline(fIn, path)) {
    Image img(path);
    img.detect_and_draw();
    cvWaitKey();
    cvDestroyWindow("result");
}
```

It's not entirely clear, but `cvDestroyWindow` sounds a lot like something that really belongs in a destructor as well, but I'm not certain enough about how these pieces fit together to be sure what destructor -- perhaps `Image`'s, more likely something else.

I'd note that `detect_and_draw` virtually screams "this code ignores the single responsibility principle". It lists two responsibilities in the name, and appears to have at least a third (saving the file) as well.

Comment: I like this method, and it makes sense. As for detect_and_draw, I'll be sure to change that...